# JS google tag script issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using *JS* below in google TAG to capture **wordpress** category(dresses in this example)... It works good for one category(without the else if part). But, I want to use it for more then one.

```
    function() {
           var categoryArr = {{categoryArray}};
           if (categoryArr == "") {
               return "none";
           }
           var contentType = "article";
           for (i = 0; i < categoryArr.length; i++) {
               if (categoryArr[i] == "dresses") {
                  contentType = "dresses";
               }
               else if (categoryArr[i] == "nails") {
                  contentType = "nails";
                  break;
               }
           }
           return contentType; 
    }
```

I played with it a lot but can't make it work. Total beginner.

Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Theres a lot of issues with this code, I don't know really where to start

Comment: Run your code through a JS validator like http://jslint.com or http://jshint.com

Comment: you have to be really specific with "make it work": what does it do now? what is it supposed to do? what have you tried?. "Here is this code that does not work. Make it work" is not a good question.

Comment: Thanks for answers, it's google TAG js that recognizes category from WP so it can be displayed in Google Analytics. If I take this part out:

else if (categoryArr[i] == "nails") {
contentType = "nails";

Then it works good, but it only recognizes one category(dresses). I need to use it for multiple categories.

Comment: Formatted the Code part and content

Comment: You have missed out the `}` brace between `if` and `else if`. :)